# How can I decrypt Snapchat .nomedia files?

Tags: ruby, encryption, photo, delete-file, snapchat

Recently, all of my Snapchat photos and videos got deleted, so I have been trying to get them back. Apparently, Snapchat stores photos/videos in a file, then hides that file using a .nomedia extension. However, to make it harder to find, we apparently need to decrypt Snapchat .nomedia files using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'openssl'

data = File.open('blob', 'r:ASCII-8BIT').read
c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-ECB')
c.decrypt
c.key = 'M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4'
o = ''.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
data.bytes.each_slice(16) { |s| o += c.update(s.map(&:chr).join) }
o += c.final
File.open('blob.jpg', 'w') { |f| f.write(o) }
```

Sadly, I have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: That's a [Ruby program](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), so you need to run it using a Ruby interpreter.  Also, shouldn't you provide a link to the place where you obtained the code so that others can look there to see if there is any documentation?

Comment: It looks like this code will read from a file named `blob` in the current working directory, and it will use the key `M02cnQ51Ji97vwT4`.  You might need to change those variables depending on the name of your file and the key used to encrypt it.

Comment: David Grayson, I honestly have no idea what to do with this, or where to put this. I'm as lost as you, and I myself am trying to figure out this code, which is why I came here to get an answer. It would make sense if I were a programmer of some sort, but I barely no anything about programming, and I'm really frustrated. -_-

Comment: And I found the code here: https://gist.github.com/jamescmartinez/6913761

Answer (score 1):

You got this sample from

> http://features.en.softonic.com/retrieve-deleted-snapchat-photos ?

but you will need to adapt some values like filename (with extension !), key etc.
If all you files are store in an encrypted .nomedia file you would need to decrypt each file with the exact encryption key, not that from the sample.
If you don't have the key I'm afraid you are lost, at the site linked they may callt he encyption weak, but even if you were an experienced coder, the challenge would be daunting.

I read something about hese files no longer being encrypted, so you could try renaming them with the correct file extension and opening them, good luck !

My advise: don't store files on snapshat to keep them, that's contrary to the purpose of snapshat, though on the new policy this is changing as it seems.
Keep them local and on a backup and redundantly in the cloud on a remote storage like www.Box.com, Google drive, dropbox etc..

Comment: what is they key for?

Comment: encryption most of the time works with one or more keys, it's what makes it possible to make an encrypted file back to its original, usable state, I suggest you do some reading at wikipedia